# How to insert code snippet for Debug.WriteLine(); in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, code-snippets

I can simply insert code snippet for the `Console.WriteLine();` by just using the `cw` 
with  <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. But I'm not able to find the same option for the `Debug.WriteLine();`.

I want to know how can we customize the code snippet template in Visual Studio for Windows Phone?

Comment: Didn´t know about the "cw" shortcut! thanks for mentioning that one ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2010 (and assuming other versions as well), there is not a snippet for `Debug.WriteLine()`. In that case, you'll need to create a custom snippet. Fortunately, it isn't that hard with the available resources:

- [MSDN: Creating and Using IntelliSense Code Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [The Snippet Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb973770)
- [Snippet Designer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/B08B0375-139E-41D7-AF9B-FAEE50F68392) (Visual Studio Extension) and the related [CodePlex Site](http://snippetdesigner.codeplex.com)

If you're using ReSharper, then [Code Templates](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_templates.html) and specifically [Live Templates](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Templates__Applying_Templates__Creating_Source_Code_Using_Live_Templates.html) are a quick and easy option.

Comment: I created a `dw` [VS2015 snippet that expands to `Debug.WriteLine`](https://gist.github.com/schmich/45ab9181ab83fb74deca).